# Sending message to a unique socket

Tags: node.js, chat, socket.io

I am using node.js and socket.io to create a chat application. How to send message to another socket, I know the id of the socket or  the username only. There are no rooms , clients chat one on one.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With Socket.IO, you aren't restricted to only using the socket object within the callback of the connection function. You can create an object that stores the socket object for a particular username and look up the socket to send a message to when a client emits a message. You would need to transmit the intended target with every message.

Example:

```
var sockets = {};

...

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('set nickname', function (name) {
        sockets[name] = socket;
    });
    socket.on('send message', function (message, to) {
        sockets[to].emit(message);
    });
});
```

See more examples on the [examples page of Socket.IO's website](http://socket.io/#how-to-use).

Comment: How to handle "to" is doesn't belong to any nickname? For example;  Nickname "A" is send msg to Nickname "B" , Nickname "B" is send msg to Nickname "C". And there is no Nickname "C"  Then give error = "cannot read property 'emit' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You can check the username property of all sockets like this:

```
socket.on('send message', function(message,to){

    io.sockets.clients().forEach(function (socket) {

        if (socket.username==to){socket.emit(message);} 

    });

 });
```